# Problema al definir una variable en un juego de Blackjack en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y en este momento estoy creando un juego de Blackjack para 2-3 jugadores, para ello hice cuatro módulos pero al correr el programa me sale que una variable está indefinida, a pesar de que la retorné previamente.

Por otro lado, además de ese error me gustaría saber si presento algún otro error y si me podrían ayudar a corregirlo; me sería de gran utilidad.

A continuación dejo la parte del código que presenta el problema en cuestión:

**main.py**

```
import time

from ganador import ganador_2J
from ganador import ganador_3J
from jugadores import jugadores
from turnos import turno

continuar=1

while continuar!=0:
  print("Juego de Blackjack")

  print("")

  número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  jugadores(número_jugadores)

  if número_jugadores==2:

    print(f" Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.")

    time.sleep(3)

    jugador_1= 0
    jugador_2= 0

    for i in range(número_jugadores):
      print(f"Inicia el jugador {i+1}:")

      time.sleep(3)

      if i==0:
        jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])

        print(f"Turno Finalizado. Espera a tu Oponente...\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("")

      else:
        jugador_2 =turno(nombre_jugadores[i])

        print(f"Turno finalizado.\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print(f"Eligiendo al ganador...")

        time.sleep(5)

        print("")
```

**jugadores.py**

```
def jugadores(número_jugadores):

  """ Esta función permite nombre de cada uno de los jugadores. """

  nombre_jugadores=[]

  print("")

  for i in range(número_jugadores):

    nombre_jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")

    nombre_jugadores.append(nombre_jugador)

  return(nombre_jugadores,nombre_jugador)
```

**turnos.py**

```
import random
import time

def turno(mazo_de_cartas,nombre_jugador):
  total=0
  elección=1
  número_carta=1

  cartas_jugador=[]

  print(f"Turno de {nombre_jugador}:")

  while elección!=0 and total<21:
    valor_carta=0

    print (f"\nCarta #{número_carta}:")

    time.sleep(3)

    carta=random.choice(mazo_de_cartas)

    print(f"[carta]")

    if carta[:1] in (10,"J","Q","K"):
      cartas_jugador.append(carta)
      valor_carta=int(10)

    elif carta[:1] in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
      cartas_jugador.append(carta)
      valor_carta=int(carta[:1])  

    elif carta[:1]=="A":

      cartas_jugador.append(carta)

      valor_carta=int(input(f"¿Qué valor quieres que tenga la carta, 1 u 11?:"))

      while valor_carta!=1 or valor_carta!=11:

        if valor_carta==1:
          valor_carta=int(1)

        elif valor_carta==11:
          valor_carta=int(11)  

        else:
          valor_carta=int(input(f"¿Qué valor quieres que tenga la carta, 1 u 11?:"))

  total+=valor_carta

  time.sleep(3)

  if(número_carta>1):
    print(f"Puntaje= {total}\n")

  if(total<21):
    respuesta=2

    while respuesta==2:

      respuesta=int(input(f"¿Qué deseas hacer?:\n1. Pedir otra carta\n2. Mirar tus cartas\n3. Finalizar el turno\n"))

      if(respuesta==1):
        número_carta+=1

      elif(respuesta==2):    
        print(f"Cartas: {cartas_jugador}\n")

        time.sleep(3)

      else:
        elección=0
        return(total)

  elif total==21:
    cartas_jugador.append(carta)

    print(f"Has hecho un Blackjack!")
    return(total)

  else:
    print(f"Has perdido!")
    return(0)
```

Al correr el programa me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Juego de Blackjack

Ingrese el número de jugadores:2

Ingrese el nombre del jugador 1:A
Ingrese el nombre del jugador 2:B
 Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.
Inicia el jugador 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])
NameError: name 'nombre_jugadores' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes jaja

**jugadores.py**

```
def jugadores(número_jugadores):

  """ Esta función permite nombre de cada uno de los jugadores. """

  nombre_jugadores=[]

  print("")

  for i in range(número_jugadores):

    nombre_jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")

    nombre_jugadores.append(nombre_jugador)

  #return(nombre_jugadores,nombre_jugador)
  return(nombre_jugadores) # nombre_jugador no hace falta pues nombres_jugadores ya tiene todos los nombres.
```

**main.py**

Aquí estás llamando a jugadores de la siguiente manera

```
jugadores(número_jugadores)
```

Pero tu función jugadores te está devolviendo información. Es precisamente aquí donde empieza tu error. Debería recoger esa info.

```
nombre_jugadores = jugadores(número_jugadores)
```

Este variable `nombre_jugadores` será una tupla con todos los nombres. Así lo que haces es que queda declarada con la info que tu quieres también en tu `main` y así cuando haces `jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i]` ya existirá.

Un saludo!

**PD: NO TENGAS ACENTOS**

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**

Me parece tienes un lío con el tema de que variables hay que definir, recibir con las funciones.

Fíjate como en tu `main` llamas a la función `turno`,

```
if i==0:
    jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])
```

Aquí le estas diciendo dos cosas,

- Antes del igual lo que pones antes del igual es que recibirás una variable que será el nombre de un jugador.
- Despúes del igual defines que a la variable le pasas el nombre de un jugador.

Ahora veamos **turno.py**, empecemos por lo que tienes en la primera línea,

```
def turno(mazo_de_cartas,nombre_jugador):
```

Le estás diciendo que le pasas 2 parámetros, el primero es `mazo_de_cartas` y el segundo el nombre de un jugador. Pero, ¿te acuerdas lo que te he dicho un par de líneas más arriba? Solo le pasas el nombre de un jugador, por lo tanto te falta pasarle el mazo de cartas.

En cuanto los `return` el funcionamiento es parecido, lo que tu pongas en el return es lo que tu estabas recogiendo antes del igual al llamar tu función, en este caso era también un nombre de jugador.

Es difícil por aquí solucionar tus problemas, porque cada uno al arreglarlo arrastra otro. Te recomiendo un parón, repasar como funcionan las funciones con algún tutorial de youtube y intentar hacerlo de nuevo (a veces es mucho mejor hacer algo de nuevo que buscar los fallos). Piensa que ya la pregunta anterior era más de lo mismo.

**¡ANIMO!**

Comment: Entonces en el módulo `turnos.py` la función `turno(mazo_de_cartas, nombre_jugador)` la debo hacer con un solo argumento o debo cambiar `¨nombre_jugador` por `nombre_jugadores`

Comment: @LIeims Al correr el código con ese cambio, ya me sale un error de pérdida de argumento en la función `turno`

Comment: Ahora lo miraba, el problema es que tienes un lío importante de como funcionan, los return y el tema de como pasar y recibir parámetros en una función. A medida que resuelves uno, te sale otro.

Comment: @LIeims es verdad, es algo que la verdad me ha dado un poco de dificultad, otra cosa que podría hacer es simplemente hacer el mazo de cartas con una sola lista y no con dos, creo que simplificaría mucho las cosas

Comment: Mira lo que puse, yo creo que vale la pena un parón para repasar las funciones y luego verás que todo es más sencillo.